# How to get all available url in a codeigniter project?

Tags: codeigniter

How to get all available url in a codeigniter project i.e. working url with controller and method

Answer (score 1):

Assume our URL like is this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>controller_name/FunctionName/"></a>
```

assume in your array you have data like this

```
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo $item['id'];
        echo $item['name'];
        echo $item['contact'];
        echo $item['mail'];
    }
```

so if you want to pass this with your URL

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>controller_name/FunctionName/<?php echo $item['id']?>/<?php echo $item['name']?>/<?php echo $item['contact']?>/"></a>
```

so in controller method

```
public function FunctionName($url_id, $url_$name, $url_contact) #this to tell the function there are some incoming values. Order is Important
{
    $id = $url_id;
    $name = $$url_$name;
    $contact = $url_contact;

    echo "My ID is ".$id;
    echo "My Name is ".$name;
    echo "My Contact Number is ".$contact;

    #This variable contain data which you passed
}
```